# I can't save Image to file

Tags: java

```
public void selectAndConvert(){
        DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
        for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()){

            ImageResource inImage = new ImageResource(f);
            ImageResource gray = makeGray(inImage);

            String fname = inImage.getFileName();
            String newName ="gray-" + fname;
            gray.setFileName(newName);
            gray.draw();
            gray.save();
           }
    }
```

`makeGray()`convert image to grayscale.

After I run it , I couldn't see any new file in the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getFileName is probably returning a complete path (eg c:\...\images\test.png). Prepending "gray-" would result in gray-c:\...

Try finding the last '\' and then inserting "gray-" right after that.